# Drawback of having long php session

Tags: php, session

Our user has requested to have long session time out (8 hrs) for our php application .I was  just wondering about the disadvantages of doing so in production server. In this case will it increase the resource management on the server and will the user be ever logged out in the event where the user makes a request to the website after every 5 hour?Any suggestion would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: If sessions are stored in a directory you can't control then there is the possibility that users are prematurely logged out.  E.g.: A web host I used by default stored session info in a temp directory that was cleared out at random intervals.  Some users weren't making it past 15-20 minutes of inactivity before being logged out.  Changing where sessions were saved fixed it.

Comment: What access does he/she requires? You can also run a `php` session locally (with `php -a`) use `sshfs` to open files as well as port forwarding for database access.

Comment: One major downside to long php sessions is if some one leaves their browser open and some one else sits down at their workstation they could potentially do something malicious say 7 hours after the first user logged in.  To curb things like this you will want the user to re-authenticate when performing certain tasks which basically eliminates the point of having long sessions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there's a longer sessions that would mean more data to be stored on the server at the same time, since sessions do not destroy that fast.

Beyond that, longer sessions would just mean less memory used to create/delete session data.